# Change cell line based on another cell number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There is a way where I can do something like that? :   `=D{K2}`
Where D is column and {K2} defines the line based on K2 value
Ex : `K2=5  ->   =D{K2}  ->  =D5`

Comment: Use `=INDEX(D:D,K2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=INDIRECT("D"&K2)` With the given example this will get you a reference to the value of cell D5.